# Cannot connect to database (no more data to read from this socket)

Tags: oracle, datagrip

I am trying to connect to the database. but every time i try  this error pop up :

Connection to Oracle - @obelix.fri.uniza.sk failed.
   [08000][17410] No more data to read from socket
[image: my attempt to log in]

I tried everything what i found on the internet.
I think problem is in my computer, because from another one i can acces exactly the same database

Comment: That error says "Oracle" butbyouev tagged SQL Server? You've not shown any code here either, so this isn't going to be oossy for anyone to answer as it stands.

Comment: i added image. there is no code. I just cannoct connect to the database  using datagrip or sql developer. they both say the same

Comment: I've removed the SQL Server tag, as this clearly has nothing to do with it. It's really important you tag the RDBMS your using, not just any one.

Comment: Try using connection type: Service name (instead of SID).

Comment: what should i write into "Service"?

Comment: Do you know what the Oracle database is , and what the JDBC version being used by SQL Developer is? The Ora-17410 is a general connectivity error, so it could be a number of things, even firewall. The first place to start would be to check the JDBC driver version and the database version are compatible. Then try to get the DBA to check the server/alert logs for any clues.